# Azure: moving web apps connected to VPN to another subscription

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-vpn

I have a couple of web applications deployed in Azure and I would like to move them to another subscription. The problem is that these apps are connected to the VPN gateway which cannot be moved. I suppose that if I will ask support stuff to move my applications, applications will be disconnected from the old VPN. Am I right and is there any better way to switch to the new subscription with minimal service interruption?

Answer (score -1):

You have a good question. Actually, VPN gateways *can* be moved between subscriptions. However, the migration between subscriptions is all or nothing. If you want to migrate subscriptions, *everything* within that subscription will be migrated to the other.

Our support engineers will migrate everything, including VPN gateways, with minimal interruption. Please open a support ticket and our support engineers will be happy to take care of this migration for you.

Thanks,
Bridget [MSFT]